# Metadata managed and crawled properties, finding the right one?

Tags: managed-metadata, managed-property, content-search-web-part, refiner, crawled-property

I'm attempting to run a content search web part working with a refinement web part using managed metadata that I have in my site collection term store.  I have mapped a Refinablestring00 managed property to what I thought was the correct crawled property but when I define my refiners it does not come back with any results.  I know I'm supposed to be using the "ows_" crawled properties but otherwise I'm just guessing.  Is there a way to find out for sure what crawled property I should be using for a given term store or managed metadata category?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Re-index site->

  1. On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.
  2. Under Search, click Search and offline availability.
  3. In the Reindex site section, click Reindex site.
  4. A warning appears, click Reindex site again to confirm. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

Answer (score 1):

The internal name of the MMS site column will always be part of the crawled property name. So you can simply search for that. For MMS there are always two crawled properties: one containing the default label (text) and one for the term guid (called taxid in crawled property name).

If you don't know the internal name of the MMS site column you can go the list or library settings where it is used. Click on the site column and the URL will contain the internal name for it.

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried this and had no success.  For example, my column name is Resource Category, so I mapped both ows_taxid_resource_x0020_category and well as ows_resource_x0020_category and I get "no Refers to show".

However, if I use owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo or Tags than I get ALL the metadata categories, not just the ones that I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have some data in the index the current user has access to?

Comment: yes, when I do a preview refiners it shows all the data, just doesn't refine the data

Answer (score 0):

You can map your managed property "Refinablestring00" with your managed metadata column's crawled property named like "ows_coulumnName". You should verify the below points:

1. Is there any list data associated with the managed metadata column?
2. While mapping crawled property to managed property is there any duplicate crawled properties listing?
3. Created "Refinablestring00" is Refinable or not?

Comment: Vishnu, thank you.  That would be my question though, how do I know what my managed metadata's crawled property name is as it's not always evident? Is there a way to find out what crawled property name that managed metadata is associated with?

Comment: In Site Settings -> Search Schema., Search for your "RefinableString00" and edit.
Goto "Mappings to crawled properties" section and in "Add a mapping" just search for the site column name it should be "ows_columnName".
Which will be your crawled property.

Comment: The site column name cannot be found. Maybe there is a bug in Sharepoint, so that no corresponding crawled property is created for site columns.